# How to split a pandas serie in two columns separate by comma

Tags: pandas, split, series

I have a pandas serie.

```
13/08/2020 5:54;;; xxxxxxxxx
13/08/2020 5:54;;; yyyyyyy
```

How do I do to split the serie by  ";;;" into two new columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html). By default it returns a series with a list of values, but you can set the expand parameter flag to get it to return a dataframe:

```
mydf = myseries.str.split(";;;", expand=True)
```